# Alpha transparency in Blender 2.90

Tags: transparency

I've been trying to learn from a tutorial where the author uses **Blender 2.8**. He uploads a reference picture and makes it 50% transparent by ticking "use alpha" box and setting "opacity" to 50%. When he does that, the sketch in his reference images is still visible, but a bit transparent.

However, I'm using ***Blender 2.90*** where there's "transparency" setting. I enabled that and set the opacity to 50%. I was using the exact same pictures as reference pictures but the images became empty white sheets after enabling "transparency". ***How can I change my reference images so I can see through them while modeling?*** Here's a reference to the tutorial I'm talking about:  https://youtu.be/Hf2esGA7vCc (the relevant part starts from 5:47).

Comment: What do your reference images look like? Do they have actual transparency, or just black (or white) backgrounds?

Comment: i just tried with 2.90 and 2.91 and "transparency" works exactly like "use alpha" does in the tutorial, so dunno, maybe a bug with your setup (gpu?)

Comment: I asked a more detailed version of this question (with screenshots) here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233517/how-can-i-set-reference-images-to-semi-transparent-in-blender-2-93-2 Hopefully the screenshots will help this question get a good answer.

Comment: I believe this is caused by an issue with Intel Graphics on Linux; are you using Intel Graphics on Linux? https://developer.blender.org/T77572

Answer (score 0):

If you added it as a reference image, it should be under the Image Properties tab:

[image: Transparency]

Answer (score 0):

When I followed the procedure you did, it worked perfectly although it was very bright still so I had to turn the opacity to something more like 0.25 to really see through it very well. :)