# How can I set reference images to semi-transparent in Blender 2.93.2?

Tags: image, transparency

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hf2esGA7vCc#t=5m49s) on modeling. In it, the person adds a reference image and then sets its opacity to 0.5 using the Object Data Properties menu which looks like this:

[image] [image]

In Blender 2.93.2, the Object Data Properties menu looks slightly different. I tried ticking "Opacity" and setting the value to 0.500, but it has no effect:

[image] [image]

How can I achieve a similar transparency effect in Blender 2.93.2?

My system: Arch Linux latest, Intel HD Graphics P630.

Comment: Note: there are other similar questions on Stack Exchange Blender, but I looked at all of them and none of them provided detailed screenshots of what they tried. Also, many of them aren't quite on the latest version of Blender. So I think this question still adds value and will hopefully attract a correct answer (which none of the other questions have).

Comment: Similar questions are: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195377/alpha-transparency-in-blender-2-90 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200732/opacity-for-reference-image-not-working

Comment: This issue only seems to happen on Intel graphics; it does not happen when I use my laptop's NVidia card. I will file a bug report against Blender (or find one if someone else has already filed it) and create an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://developer.blender.org/T77572) when using Blender on Intel Graphics on Linux that was introduced in Blender 2.83.

I found that the work-around of running Blender with

```
MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965 blender
```

fixes the issue on my system; however, I get noticeably worse performance with choppy framerate even when panning a simple 2-object scene.